# Booting vdi image on virtualbox using libvirt

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, libvirt

I am not able to boot a vdi image on virtualbox using libvirt .It keeps showing me "Bootable medium not found".  I have tried booting it manually with virtualbox GUI and it boots without any problem. May there is some problem with my libvirt domain XML .

---

```
<os> 
<type>hvm</type> 
<boot dev='hd'/>           
</os>
```

---

```
<devices>
<disk type='file' device='disk'> 
<source file='disk.vdi'/> 
<target dev='hdd'/> 
</disk>
</devices>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would try to convert image to another format just to make sure that everything is ok

try something like that: qemu-img convert -f vdi disk.vdi -O qcow2 disk.qcow2
and then: qemu-kvm disk.qcow2 -m 1024